# What's the deal with code reviews?

Tags: code-reviews

I've been wondering about code reviews recently, based on how many questions I've seen on here talking about them.

Between my internships, contracts, and full time jobs, I've worked for six different companies, and only one of them has done code reviews.

At the last two places I've worked, code was good (or at least good enough) if all the unit tests passed, and it got the stamp of approval from our tester.  We were all compotent programmers, so if the code worked, we were happy.

Now, there were a handful of times where something came up months or years down the line that might have been caught in a review, but they were so few and far between that I'm not sure it'd be useful.

I guess my question is:

1. Do you consider reviews to be useful?
2. How often do you do them?
3. How much of your time is spent reviewing code?

Comment: You are polling for people's opinions, and that [doesn't really work with the Q&A format of the site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @YannisRizos Would this be more on topic if it was asking what the benefit of code reviews is? Or why code-reviews are so important?

Comment: I didn't realize programmers.stackexchange was as strict about this as stackoverflow.  It seems like many of the questions here are opinion-based.

Comment: @Rachel _Probably_ (although you should [check for duplicates first](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcode-reviews%5D+closed%3A0)). This question has already too many answers and a substantial edit would invalidate most of them, so preferably you should ask a new question /cc: Matt Grande.

Comment: @MattGrande [We welcome _some_ subjective questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about-subjective-questions). Your question has multiple problems though, the most obvious being that you ask three distinct questions. Furthermore, the wording doesn't help, there is nothing in the question text that invites the sharing of experiences over opinions...

Comment: "there is nothing in the question text that invites the sharing of experiences over opinions"

I really think that's a lame excuse.  I specifically ask how often people do them, how much of their time, etc.  I think it's clear I'm placing value in peoples experiences.

I also don't think this was a duplicate.  There were, granted, similar questions, but I didn't see any that questioned if reviews are valuable.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why this was closed, whereas this (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120321/is-orm-an-anti-pattern/120338) remains open.  "what do you think about ORM? What are the pros and the cons?"  Is that so different from what I wrote?

Comment: @MattGrande I agree it's also a not constructive question, and I argued as such in the comments. I also voted to close (at the time I was not a moderator) and the question was indeed closed, but then reopened by the community. That same process can happen for your question... It may appear that I benefited from that question since my answer is highly voted but if you check it's revision history you'll notice that my close vote was the first one it got. I even stupidly closed it again a few minutes ago, having forgotten it was reopened by the community.

Comment: I think the key question is whether the ANSWERS to this question, plus any subsequent answers that would be posted if the question were re-opened, would be USEFUL to future seekers of knowledge.  That is, if tomorrow, somebody searches for "benefits of code review" or "reasons to code review" or something similar; will that person benefit from these answers.  Having read some of the answers below, I think YES, a future searcher would benefit from the presence of this question.  I don't have the rep to vote to re-open this question, but if I DID, I certainly WOULD.

Answer (score 9):

1. Absolutely. There are lots of bugs you can catch early via code review. And there are certain types of bugs you can hardly catch any way else than code review (e.g. some concurrency bugs). But what is even more important: (group) code reviews are a great way to spread and share a coherent, consistent view of design, architecture, coding idioms and best practices throughout the development team. The only better way I can imagine is pair programming - which in fact is an extreme form of code review.
   The prime goal of (classic, formal) code reviews is in fact not catching bugs already present in the code, but preventing (future) bugs from getting into the code, via the above mentioned continuous communication / mentoring / discussion between team members, generated during review meetings.
   This is probably one of the reasons why code reviews are still rare. They show their real benefit only in the long term, so it takes perseverance to get there, and most managers (and developers alike) have never experienced it.
2. In our current project, we have been doing it only occasionally up to now, but it is bound to change. The new aim is to get every code change reviewed by someone else before it gets into production. In an earlier project, we did that and it was useful. In an even earlier project, we did formal group code reviews, and it was still useful, but fairly slow and time consuming. We couldn't have reviewed every code change in that manner without slowing down our pace of development enormously. But for some types of projects, even that pays off. If human lives are at stake, your prime motivation isn't saving dimes.
3. Up to now it was no more than an hour per week on average. According to our new process, this is surely going to increase. In the earlier projects mentioned, IIRC it was 2-4 hours per week on average.

Answer (score 5):

Let's think about the best case scenario: the code is perfect (which will never happen)

**Would code reviews be useless?
No**, everyone involved in the review would learn something and the review would facilitate conversation and exchange of ideas.

Anything less than the best case scenario has been addressed by other answers.

As far as how much time should be spent reviewing and how the review should be structured...this is highly dependent on many departmental/organizational factors and cannot be answered without this context.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention whether your coders got the code right on the first try, or if they commited code where QA found bugs that required fixing. If QA is finding bugs, perhaps doing code reviews would lower the number of bugs they find. If QA is finding less of the more obvious bugs, they have more time to find the less-obvious bugs. And the more time they spend finding the less-obvious bugs, the less likely your customers will find those same bugs.

Comment: That's a great point.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Much can be learned from reviewing code, even if it's correct and simply written poorly.
2. As often as time allows, usually daily. At least a few times per week is enough.
3. Usually 30 minutes to an hour, depending on the nature of the review.

Remember, just because every company doesn't conduct code reviews doesn't mean it's a waste of time to do so. Perhaps they don't all simply realize the benefits or even know to include them as part of their development process.

Comment: Oh definately, they could be extremely useful, but I've just never had that much exposure to them.  Not every company unit tests, and I think that's pretty important!

Answer (score 1):

1 - I do consider reviews useful, even if it's an informal process. Unit tests passing doesn't mean you caught all the cases, and unit tests attempt to test code in isolation, so you might have written code that ignored something that may cause problems when your code is integrated with other components. Plus, it might help you improve your ability and style if people can suggest better ways to write what you have written.

2 - I do them if I'm the reviewer for other people's fixes, though in my last company, we used Review Board and I would be requested frequently to look at people's code. I also sometimes glance at major code changes to see if the changes are sane.

3 - Perhaps 5% of my total time.

I always try to get someone to look at my code. As competent as you may be, it's good to have other people you trust to look at your code and see if they can offer up suggestions or give you the thumbs up.

And here's the link to [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/), which can hook in with source control systems like svn and git.

Answer (score 1):

In some shops pair-programming has taken the place of code reviews. I suppose you can think of pair programming as a process of continuous code review.

In the humanities there is a famous saying that "Even Homer nods". Meaning that even if you are the worlds greatest coder, sometimes you are going to be distracted, off your game, or just plain screwing up. A second set of eyes is incredibly helpful in catching stuff like this. The earlier bugs or 'mis-features' are caught, the cheaper they are to fix. Sometimes these mistakes will pass existing tests, but be laying like booby-traps for when the code needs to be extended.

It also has the side effect of keeping everybody in the team at least a little aware of how the other bits work. This help avoid disasters where the one person who knew how the accounts receivable code worked is hit by a bus or leaves the team.

Comment: Well, I don't see what The Simpson's has to do with anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

I consider code reviews very useful and helpful.  Even if by some miracle the code is bug free it opens up opportunities to valuable insight.  I like to see how to do things differently and/or sometimes better.  When I do reviews I may also pick up something new or better while looking at the code someone else wrote.

How often they are done depends on what we are changing.  If it is a bugfix then it is likely it will go straight to QA after the developer submits a merge request.  If it is something larger and time permits then the code will be reviewed.

The amount of time spent reviewing depends on the code and the developer.  Some developers are more adept than others and some code changes are bigger than others so it varies. It never goes over an hour for me...plus the meeting will have about it (~30 minutes).